# Error while opening WCF service host connection

Tags: wcf, binding, port

I was unable to open the connection for my ServicHost. I have initially used the 8080 port it worked before.But now it is not working. I see some error (below) with my App.Conifg.Please let me know where the bug in.

This is a simple EmployeeWCF Demo app with the IEmployeeService interface and EmployeeService class.

### App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="EmployeeWCFService.EmployeeService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint name ="httpBind" address="EmployeeService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EmployeeWCFService.IEmployeeService" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint name ="netTcpBind" address="EmployeeService" binding="netHttpBinding" contract="EmployeeWCFService.IEmployeeService" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint name="mexBind" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" ></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9090"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9093"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

### ConsoleCode:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EmployeeWCFService.EmployeeService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The connection host is opened at the time " + DateTime.Now);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

### Error I am Facing while opening WCF Servicehost:

> Additional information: A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://localhost:9090/EmployeeService'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a typo in your configuration file. The second service endpoint ought to use NetTcpBinding instead of NetHttpBinding, which causes that the two serivce endpoints has the same listening uri address.
Feel free to contact me if the problem still exists.

Comment: What ever the port I am using I am getting the same error....I was able to create the object for servicehost ,but when opening the host I am facing issue....Is there sum thing I need to do with config.

Comment: You are right, there is a typo in your config. The second service endpoint ought to use NetTcpBinding instead of NetHttpBinding.